# functions for uploading a file does not work

Tags: php, function, file-upload, image-uploading

I met some trouble wjile trying to put in a function elements for uploading files.

I have a form that contains an input type file but when I try to save it it does not work.

I've made a function that should all record and save, then return a message, but all works fine except the upload file.

Here below is my function

```
/**
 * Enregistrement d'un nouvel athlète
 * @param type $nom
 * @param type $prenom
 * @param type $date_naissance
 * @param type $localisation
 * @param type $taille
 * @param type $poids
 * @param type $actif
 * @param type $biographie
 * @param type $url_photo
 * @return string|null
 */
function recordNewAthlete($nom, $prenom, $date_naissance, $localisation, $taille, $poids, $actif, $biographie, $fileuplouad) {
    $input_nom = mysql_real_escape_string($nom);
    $input_prenom = mysql_real_escape_string($prenom);
    $input_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(mysql_real_escape_string($date_naissance)));
    $input_localisation = mysql_real_escape_string($localisation);
    $input_taille = mysql_real_escape_string($taille);
    $input_poids = mysql_real_escape_string($poids);
    $input_actif = mysql_real_escape_string($actif);
    $input_biographie = ($biographie);
    if (isset($input_nom) && !empty($input_nom)) {
        if ($_FILES['$fileuplouad']['error']) {
            switch ($_FILES['$fileuplouad']['error']) {
                case 1: // UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE     
                    echo"Le fichier dépasse la limite autorisée par le serveur (fichier php.ini) !";
                    break;
                case 2: // UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE     
                    echo "Le fichier dépasse la limite autorisée dans le formulaire HTML !";
                    break;
                case 3: // UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL     
                    echo "L'envoi du fichier a été interrompu pendant le transfert !";
                    break;
                case 4: // UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE     
                    echo "Le fichier que vous avez envoyé a une taille nulle !";
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            // $_FILES['url_photo1']['error'] vaut 0 soit UPLOAD_ERR_OK     
            // ce qui signifie qu'il n'y a eu aucune erreur    
            $_FILES['$fileuplouad']['name'] = mktime() . $_FILES['$fileuplouad']['name'];
            $url1 = $_FILES['$fileuplouad']['name'];
            $chemin_destination = 'web/teamfrancestron/www/admin/uploads/';
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['$fileuplouad']['tmp_name'], $chemin_destination . $_FILES['$fileuplouad']['name']);
            $tartget_path = $chemin_destination . $_FILES['$fileuplouad']['name'];
            $query = "INSERT INTO `stg_man_athletes` SET
                    `nom` = '{$input_nom}', 
                    `prenom` = '{$input_prenom}', 
                    `date_naissance` = '{$input_date}', 
                    `localisation` = '{$input_localisation}', 
                    `taille` = '{$input_taille}', 
                    `poids` = '{$input_poids}', 
                    `etat_activite` = '{$input_actif}', 
                    `description` = '{$input_biographie}', 
                    `url_photo` = '{$target_path}'";
            mysql_query($query);
            if (mysql_affected_rows() >= 0) {
                return "<div class='success'>Enregistrement de l'Athlète terminé, vous pouvez continuer vos actions.</div>"
                ;
            } else {
                return "<div class='error'>Erreur fatale lors de l'enregistrement, veuillez réessayer ulterieurement.</div>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The trouble is that it does not move any file, in the defined path.

I call my function like that

```
$message_enregistr_athlete = recordNewAthlete($_POST['nom'], $_POST['prenom'], $_POST['date_naissance'], $_POST['localisation'], $_POST['taille'], $_POST['poids'], $_POST['etat_activite'], $_POST['description'], 'userfile');
```

and I just echo the result where I want to see if upload is ok.
the sql query is ok, all fields works fine.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated

Comment: you should debug before posting here for help. echo variables in various stages of your code to see what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make your error_repoting to all ie, `error_repoting(1);`, and see if you are getting any error.
2. If your files are too large try the below:

Two PHP configuration options control the maximum upload size: `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. Both can be set to, say, “10M” for 10 megabyte file sizes.

However, you also need to consider the time it takes to complete an upload. PHP scripts normally time-out after 30 seconds, but a 10MB file would take at least 3 minutes to upload on a healthy broadband connection (remember that upload speeds are typically five times slower than download speeds). In addition, manipulating or saving an uploaded image may also cause script time-outs. We therefore need to set PHP’s max_input_time and max_execution_time to something like 300 (5 minutes specified in seconds)

In .htaccess add this code,

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

Or you can make the settings in your php page itself using `ini_set`

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Ref: http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, Actualy no mistakes does appears and the files are not too large, for the test I used a 124ko image

Comment: I've set it to one, but nothing is displayed

Comment: I think I got it, change `$_FILES['$fileuplouad']['error']` to `$_FILES[$fileuplouad]['error']` , no single quotes for `$fileuplouad`

Comment: Change this in all the places where you use `$_FILES['$fileuplouad']`

Comment: ok thanks for your reply Actualy I've done this, it returns me this 

Notice: Undefined index: userfile in /web/teamfrancestron/www/lib_php/strongman.php on line 524

Notice: Undefined index: userfile in /web/teamfrancestron/www/lib_php/strongman.php on line 542

Notice: Undefined index: tmp_name in /web/teamfrancestron/www/lib_php/strongman.php on line 545

Notice: Undefined variable: target_path in /web/teamfrancestron/www/lib_php/strongman.php on line 556
I do not understand why, because it is the name of the file in the form and this is how I called my function

Comment: Two possibilities : 1. check the name of input file in your HTML 2. Confirm that you are actually getting the posted values in your function, Try `print_r($_REQUEST)`; or `print_r($_FILES);` in in your function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have this in request [url_photo1] => stan.png But it the function it always do not recognize $_FILES[$fileuplouad]['name'] where $fileupload is the name of the fields

Comment: I'm gettinf an empty array 
Array ( )  I really do not understand why it is not there, as it should be

Comment: Chech these things : 1. confirm you have added, `enctype= multipart/form-data` in your form. 2. Try `print_r($_FILES);` just above the line `$message_enregistr_athlete = recordNewAthlete($_POST['nom'], $_POST['prenom'], $_POST['date_naissance'], $_POST['localisation'], $_POST['taille'], $_POST['poids'], $_POST['etat_activite'], $_POST['description'], 'userfile'); `

Comment: Suggestion : In your line `$message_enregistr_athlete = recordNewAthlete($_POST['nom'], $_POST['prenom'], $_POST['date_naissance'], $_POST['localisation'], $_POST['taille'], $_POST['poids'], $_POST['etat_activite'], $_POST['description'], 'userfile');` Change last parameter `'userfile'` to `$FILES['userfile']` and in function, change all `$_FILES['$fileuplouad']` to $fileuplouad, ie you can get the name of the file like this `$fileuplouad['name']`

Comment: thank you so much for your help, because of you it works fine now